# Recent Eclipse update maybe caused it to stop functioning

Tags: eclipse, jvm, heap-memory

I finally encountered my first memory-hog situation in writing libgdx applications.  In debugging it, I restarted all my apps, including my IDE.  When I tried restarting it I got an exit=1 error, and when I tried running eclipsec.exe I received the more descriptive error:

```
  Error occurred during initialization of VM
  Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Is this because I'm running it from eclipsec.exe and not the eclipse.exe my usual shortcut executes?  Both errors could be heap related in searching similar posts, though there is also the possibility with the exit=1 that it's expecting a different version of java than I've been using.  I'm also wondering if my memory-hogging app left a giant file somewhere Eclipse is trying to load back into memory upon starting?

I'd like to try some of the memory allocation lines from other answers, but am not sure where to put them in my eclipse.ini file.  Here's the possibilities:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xms1536M -Xmx1536M
-Xms4G -Xmx4G
-XX:MaxHeapSize=512m
```

Where would I insert one of these into this file?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.0.v20200915-1508.jar
--launcher.library
C:/Users/Rigel/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.0.v20200915-1442
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\Rigel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.18.0.20201210-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Update 12/20 20:30 East Coast Timezone -----------------------------

Tried the lines, and variations, right after "-vmargs".  No change.

Learned a P2BU file is a backup of the last eclipse executable before an update, so swapped out for the penultimate one.  No change.

Looked through all the folders in the Eclipse directory for some giant, dumped file it might be trying to load at start, but they all seemed to take up a tame amount of space to me.

Anything else I could try?

Comment: This `eclipse.ini` seems to be of the outdated _ Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers_ 2020-09 installed with the _Eclipse Installer_. Neither your question nor the [`eclipse.ini` file say which Java version exactly was used to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM). I recommend using an up-to-date Eclipse with the embedded Java 15 that is shipped with Eclipse since the 2020-12 version. I never heard about a P2BU file. Please improve your question instead of adding updates which makes it harder to read.

Comment: -Xms4G -Xmx4G says 'reserve 4G of heap' which your JVM suggests is not possible. Probably not a good idea to randomly copy and paste settings from other answers though without understanding what they do.